# Появление фото справа при hover эффекте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Может кто-то знает где взять заготовку примерно как на фото, такую карточку, слева изначальный вариант а справа при наведении, чтобы фото выскакивали так сбоку, вот выскакивание фото не могу найти способ реализации, помогите пожалуйста [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всего одна js функция

```css
.nut {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

img#bigi {
  width: 100%;
}

.nut:hover .prev {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nut">
<img id='bigi' src='' style="height:100%;height:100%;background:url(https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/600x1024/5/9c/alisa-devushka-krasivaya-volosy-745.jpg);background-size:cover;">
<div>
  <div class="prev">
<img src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/600x1024/5/9c/alisa-devushka-krasivaya-volosy-745.jpg" onclick="bigi.src=this.src" style="width:50px;height:100px;display:block;">
<img src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" onclick="bigi.src=this.src" style="width:50px;height:100px;display:block;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста а как сделать чтобы фото справа появлялись только при наведении ?

Comment: задать .prev:hover ?

Comment: нет, ты не понял не чтобы они менялись при наведении, меняться они должны при клике, а эти фото что справа их вообще убрать и при наведении чтобы появлялись эти окошки с дополнительными фото

Comment: не понял)) вот смотри как тут, тут они показаны как действуют
https://dfstore.com/ru/

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: круто, то что надо, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Можно так решить:

```css
.item {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.item:hover .somephoto {
  display: block;
}

.somephoto {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  display: none;
  
}

.photo {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>Какой-то товар
  <div class="somephoto">
    <div class="photo">тут фото</div>
    <div class="photo">тут фото</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='item'>Какой-то товар
  <div class="somephoto">
    <div class="photo">тут фото</div>
    <div class="photo">тут фото</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card > .image {
  background: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.card > .image > .additional {
  min-width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card > .image > .additional > .image {
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.card > .bottom {
  padding: 10px;
}
.card > .bottom .buy {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="additional">
      <div class="image">
        
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="#" class="buy">
    Купить
      
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```